# Get all links with XPath in Puppeteer (pausing or not working)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am required to use XPaths to select all links on a page, for then my Puppeteer app to click into and perform some actions. I am finding that the method (code below) is getting stuck sometimes and my crawler will be paused. Is there a better/different way of getting all links from an XPath? Or is there something in my code that is incorrect and could be pausing my app's progress?

```
try {
  links = await this.getLinksFromXPathSelector(state);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("error getting links");
  return {...state, error: e};
}
```

Which calls:

```
async getLinksFromXPathSelector(state) {
 const newPage = state.page
 // console.log('links selector');
 const links = await newPage.evaluate((mySelector) => {
   let results = [];
   let query = document.evaluate(mySelector,
     document,
     null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
   for (let i=0, length=query.snapshotLength; i<length; ++i) {
     results.push(query.snapshotItem(i).href);
   }
   return results;
 }, state.linksSelector);
  return links;
}
```

The XPath is in `state.linksSelector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`page.$x()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) to evaluate an XPath expression and obtain an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array. It may be appropriate to use [`page.waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) beforehand to ensure that the elements specified by XPath string are added to the DOM.

Then you can pass the [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array elements to the page context via [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and return an array containing the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-href) attribute values for each element.

```
const xpath_expression = '//a[@href]';
await page.waitForXPath(xpath_expression);
const links = await page.$x(xpath_expression);
const link_urls = await page.evaluate((...links) => {
  return links.map(e => e.href);
}, ...links);

console.log(link_urls);
```

Comment: This code is definitely way cleaner and easier to read. Thank you, however, the program is still getting stuck within this method - and only in a production environment, which is in a dockerized container just fyi.

Comment: turns out the main problem was upstream, but this code definitely helped. Thanks!