# Puppeteer XPATH expression to console log

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

I have a problem. :( [Chrome-console-result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15X5A.png)

```
const xpath_expression = '//*[@id="header"]/div/ul/li/a/@href';
```

The above result comes to the screen. I cannot see the results of this href to the console, so I can't see :(

Puppeteer Code :

```
wait page.goto('https://www.sitelink.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
var title = await page.$x("//*[@id='header']/div/ul/li/a/@href");
console.log(title);
```

Unsuccessful result

[unsuccesful-result-puppeteer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vguxh.png)

Comment: Maybe I cannot follow. Have you tried to expand the `href` search results in Chrome or what do you mean when you say: " I cannot see the results of this href to the console, so I can't see"

Comment: I get href data in XPATH but I can't print :( How do I pass path data to the variable and use it?

Comment: if this is dynamic content you should try to wait (for an ajax call response or something) until the data is received.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath you posted returns nothing. Regarding the structure of the XPath you posted, it seems you were looking for something like this :

```
//*[@id="mainMenu"]/div/ul/li/a/@href
```

Puppeteer code (credits to Grant Miller for most part of the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/53568112/9978746) :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.sitelink.com');
const xpath_expression = '//*[@id="mainMenu"]/div/ul/li/a';
await page.waitForXPath(xpath_expression);
const links = await page.$x(xpath_expression);
const hrefs = await page.evaluate((...links) => {
 return links.map(a => a.href);
}, ...links);
console.log(hrefs);
```

Comment: I want to show the incoming xpath data in console, that's all I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try [page.waitForXPath()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options) or [page.waitForSelector()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) to wait for an element on the page:

```
await page.waitForXPath(xpath_selector);
```